# Internet Explorer Print Preview different results from same page

Tags: html, printing, internet-explorer-8

I'm developing a web site, where one of the pages it's a collection of divs. Each div must be printed one per page. I'm setting the width/height of each div like this:

```
body .htmltemplate{
    height:1140px; padding:0px; margin:auto; width:840px;
}
```

It seems to work. Before 1140px, I had 1098px, but the divs jumped pages, so I changed it to 1140px

The problem now is that every once in a while (let say 1 of 6), the PrintPreview shows only the half (or so) of the width, and a portion of the height goes to the next page, so I have double the pages to print. In example, if I have 40 divs, I get 80 pages.

I've noticed that when this problem occurs, the CPU Usage in Task Manager jumps to 100%

Do you have any idea of what is causing this problem??? Am I missing some css attribute (I've tried page-break but no luck)???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Browsers are crap at printing WYSIWYG content. If you want good hard-copies, render them on the server as PDF and provide the file as a download.

Comment: Hi @Diodeus thanks for your response. Unfortunately, render at server is not an option, cause the customer want to see that page in the browser first, and have the chance to make a little modification